# psql not using right config file

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.6

When I attempt to start a psql server by running 'psql' in command line, I receive this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

For some reason postgres was unable to access `/tmp` so I edited my `postgresql.conf` file and assigned `unix_socket_directories` to another folder. This worked and allowed me to start a server on 5432 and I can now see a `.s.PGSQL.5432.lock` in the newly created folder. BUT, psql seems to still be looking for the lock file inside the tmp folder. So I guess my question is: How can I tell psql to look inside my newly created folder instead of /tmp?

I have run a bunch of `mdfind` commands looking for other `postgresql.conf` files but the only one I could find was in `/Library/Application\ Support/Postgress/var-9.6` and that is the config file I have already edited.

I have installed postgress from Postgres.app and NOT using brew.

OS: macOS Monterey

postgres version: 9.6

Comment: This is usually a sign that you are using a version of `psql` that was compiled to look in `/tmp`. Do you have more then one version of `psql` installed? As I recall `Postgres.app` installs in your home directory and should not be looking outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the socket directory (absolute path!) with the `-h` option of `psql`:

```sh
psql -h /socket/directory
```